# Implementation of LZ1 compression's algorithm

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, compression

I am looking for implementation of [Lempel-Zev class 1](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21090049)
 algorithm.
It would be great if it would be in one of .NET languages.
Any ogher languages is also OK, if we do not have any other.

Appreciate any help...

Thanks.

UPDATE

Have tried:
1. zlib
2. LZMA SDK
3. harpLZW

Did not help.

Comment: In spite of the link, i'm not sure to understand what LZ class 1 means : Is that a specific (and documented) format, or just a type of compression ? Are you looking for something that compress "like IBM LZ class1", or something that can actually decode a binary stream compressed by IBM LZ class 1 ?

Answer (score 0):

first it's `Lempel-Ziv` haven't heard about class 1 but i found you the `LZW` in c#
[LZW - C#](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharplzw/)